# If $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and $x_n \to x_0$, $h_n \to 0$ when $\lim \frac{f(x_n+h_n) - f(x_n)}{h_n} = f'(x_0)$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Suppose that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$, in general this is not sufficient to prove that

$$
\lim \frac{f(x_n+h_n) - f(x_n)}{h_n} = f'(x_0)
$$

for every pair of sequences $x_n \to x_0$ and $h_n \to 0$. However, it seems that and additional condition on the rate of convergence of $x_n$ should suffice since the result obviously holds in the extreme case where we consider the constant sequence $x_n = x_0, \ \forall \ n$.

My question is, is it possible to find the slowest rate of convergence for $x_n-x_0$ such that we still have $\lim \frac{f(x_n+h_n) - f(x_n)}{h_n} = f'(x_0)$? That would deppend on the rate of $h_n$ as well?

Comment: This may all be very trivial, but since $f$ is differentiable you know that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(x_0+h_n)-f(x_0)}{h_n}=f'(x)$.
So a sufficient condition on $x_n$ would clearly be that $\lvert f(x_n+h_n)-f(x_0+h_n)\rvert=o(h_n)$ and $\lvert f(x_n)-f(x_0)\rvert=o(h_n)$. But I am not sure if that helps you find the slowest possible rate of convergence.

Answer (score 3):

A sufficient condition for the statement to be true is that the sequence of ratios $\frac{x_n-x_0}{h_n}$ is bounded (for this of course have to assume each $h_n \neq 0$). Loosely speaking, the convergence $x_n \to x_0$ should be atleast "as fast/slow" as $h_n \to 0$.

To prove this, let $M>0$ be such that for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$, $|x_n - x_0| \leq M|h_n|$. Now, by definition of $f$ being differentiable at $x_0$, we have
\begin{align}
f(x_0 + h) &= f(x_0) + f'(x_0)\cdot h + r(h),
\end{align}
where $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{r(h)}{h} = 0$. Let $\epsilon>0$. Then, there is a $\delta>0$ such that for all $h$, if $|h|\leq \delta$ then $|r(h)|\leq \epsilon$.

Since $x_n \to x_0$, there is an $N_1\in \Bbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N_1$, we have $|x_n-x_0|\leq \frac{\delta}{2}$. Also, since $h_n \to 0$, there is an $N_2\in\Bbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N_2$, we have $|h_n|\leq \frac{\delta}{2}$.

So, if $n \geq \max(N_1, N_2)$, we have
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{f(x_n+h_n) - f(x_n)}{h_n} - f'(x_0)\right| &=
\left| \frac{r(x_n + h_n - x_0) - r(x_n - x_0)}{h_n} \right| \\
&\leq \frac{|r(x_n + h_n - x_0)| + |r(x_n - x_0)|}{|h_n|} \\
& \leq \frac{\epsilon |x_n + h_n - x_0| + \epsilon |x_n - x_0|}{|h_n|} \\
& \leq \epsilon \frac{2|x_n - x_0| + |h_n|}{|h_n|} \\
& \leq \epsilon (2M+1).
\end{align}
Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, this completes the proof that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{f(x_n+h_n) - f(x_n)}{h_n} = f'(x_0)$.

Comment: Nice, now it remains to prove that this rate is optimal in some sense. I found some counterexamples using the function $f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2, & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ -x^2, & x \not\in \mathbb{Q}  \end{cases}$. This function is differentiable only at $0$ and one can play with different sequences $x_n$ of rationals and $h_n$ of irrationals.

Comment: Another interesting feature is that, for every sequence $x_n \to x_0$ you can always find another sequence $h_n \to 0$ that satisfies $|x_n-x_0| = O(h_n)$ and have a sequence to approximate $f'(x_0)$.

Comment: Proving optimality is always a tricky business :)

Answer (score 2):

around $x_0$

$f(x)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)=r(x-x_0)$

where $r(0):=0$ and  $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{|r(x-x_0)|}{|x-x_0|}=0$

Then

$$\frac{f(x_n+h_n)-f(x_n)}{h_n}=f'(x_0)+\frac{r(x_n+h_n-x_0)}{h_n}+\frac{r(x_n-x_0)}{h_n}$$

$$\Big|\frac{r(x_n+h_n-x_0)}{h_n}\Big|\leq\frac{|h_n|+|x_n-x_0|}{|h_n|}\Big|\frac{r(x_n+h_n-x_0)}{x_n+h_n-x_0}\Big|\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0
$$
if $|x_n-x_0|=O(h_n)$. For the last term

$$\Big|\frac{r(x_n-x_0)}{h_n}\Big|\leq\frac{|x_n-x_0|}{|h_n|}\Big|\frac{r(x_n-x_0)}{x_n-x_0}\Big|\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0
$$
if $|x_n-x_0|=O(h_n)$. Thus, if $|x_n-x_0|=O(h_n)$, we get

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x_n+h_n)-f(x_n)}{h_n}=f'(x_0)
$$

If in addition, $f$ is continuously differentiable in some interval containing $x_0$, then no restrictions on $h_n$ (other than  to have points within the domian) are needed.

Comment: There are a couple of issues here regarding division by zero, because the only thing we should assume is that $\{h_n\}$ is a sequence of non-zero numbers such that $h_n \to 0$, and that $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence of numbers such that $x_n \to 0$ (we should certainly allow the possibility some (or all) $x_n =x_0$). Moreover, with minor modifications the entire proof goes through if we assume that $x_n-x_0 = O(h_n)$, i.e that the sequence of ratios $\frac{x_n-x_0}{h_n}$ (which is well-defined since $h_n \neq 0$) is bounded.

Comment: @user580918 I think both arguments are essentially the same, the division by zero is not really an issue because when the number that you are both multiplying and dividing is zero the left hand side is already zero so there is no need to estimate, you estimate only when it is nonzero, so you prove the limit anyway.

Comment: @mamediz division by zero is one of the worst things you can do. In this case it happens that the proof can be re-written in a way to avoid unnecessary divisions, but sometimes it can't (in which case the entire proof is rendered useless and has to be re-written completely, or worse, the claim itself might be false). So, no, division by zero is always a big issue.

Comment: @user580918: your splitting hairs here. It is implicitly understood that $r(0):=0$. Also, the result is of local type where typically (unless there some real important issues) and stays close enough to $0$ in the numerators and not at $0$. There is not more to it, this is not Navier Stokes equation or a small divisors problem.

Comment: I agree $r(0)=0$ which is clear by definition. That's not what I was objecting to. I was objecting to the multiplication and division $\dfrac{x_n-x_0}{x_n-x_0} "="1$. Clearly if you plug in $x_n = x_0$ then you have $\frac{0}{0}$ in a few places in your proof, and trying to claim this is $1$ is just nonsense. Or if you try the sequence $x_n = x_0-h_n$, then you again have division by zero issues.

Comment: Now, I'm not trying to undermine your work or anything (on the contrary: I liked most of your answer) I just wanted to point out an error, which I think is huge (because I've seen so many other incorrect proofs), but if you think it's a small error, then fine, we can certainly have different opinions on the severity of an error, but I think we could both agree it was an error and it is best to correct it. That was all my intent was.

Comment: @user580918: when either $x_n+h_n-x_0$ or $x_n-x_0$ is zero, $r=0$, so no division by $x_n+h_n-x_0$ or $x_n-x_0$ is needed as the corresponding residuals vanish. I do appreciate good discussions, in fact the order $O(h_n)$ in your initial comment was right on the money. As for optimally, I am not sure that finding he weakest growth possible is he optimal. From the point of view of numerical analysis, maybe fastest convergence is better. In this problem, highly oscillations may make to convergence to the value of the derivative at $x_0$ extremely slow of the step $h_n$ or $x_n-x_0$ disastrous.

Comment: @user580918 At this level, of course that I know that division by zero is impossible. Did you really tought that I was ok with that?

Answer (score -1):

$x_n - x_0 = \text{o}(h_n)$ is sufficient.
Just add and subtract $f(x_0)$ from numerator and split into two parts.
On the other hand if, say $x_n = x_0 + h_n$ then the limit is not equal to the derivative.

Comment: Why if $x_n = x_0 + h_2$ the limit is not the derivative? I'm pretty sure $x_n - x_0 = O(h_n)$ is sufficient; i.e it is sufficient that the ratio $\frac{x_n-x_0}{h_n}$ is bounded in order for the sequence to converge to $f'(x_0)$.

Comment: Well ... if x_n = x_0 + h_n then one easily computes the limit to be 1/2 of derivative. Just add and subtract f(x_0) to numerator and split into two parts.

Comment: umm no, it is still $f'(x_0)$. $\frac{f(x_n+h_n) - f(x_n)}{h_n} = \frac{f(x_0+2h_n) - f(x_0 + h_n)}{h_n} = \frac{f(x_0 + 2h_n) - f(x_0)}{h_n} - \frac{f(x_0+h_n)- f(x_0)}{h_n}\to 2f'(x_0) - f'(x_0) = f'(x_0)$

Comment: True ... sorry for the mess.